# stm32 USB receive more than 1 byte

Tags: c, stm32

I am trying to establish a USB communication between PC and a STM32 MCU. I want to receive an integer from a PC. (range of the integer is between 0 and 20.000). I added those lines:

To usb_cdc_if.h :

```
_weak void CDC_ReceiveCallBack(uint8_t *buf, uint32_t len);
```

To the usb_cdc_if.c

```
static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, &Buf[0]);
  USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);
  CDC_ReceiveCallBack(Buf, Len);
  return (USBD_OK);
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
.
.
.
__weak void CDC_ReceiveCallBack(uint8_t *buf, uint32_t len)
{}
```

And in the main class:

```
void CDC_ReceiveCallBack(uint8_t *buf, uint32_t len)
{

fan_speed=atoi(buf);
    memset(statusString,0x00,255);
statusStringLength = sprintf(statusString,"Fan Speed: %d ", fan_speed);
    CDC_Transmit_FS(statusString,statusStringLength);
}
```

So I can only receive 1 digit numbers. Should I add an if statement to the beginning of function and when enter is pressed, then I should receive it from buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are tyring to implement a serial connection (aka Virtual COM Port) over USB and that you have a terminal application connected to it on the PC...

If so, you need to understand that:

- The characters sent from the PC to the MCU can be chopped up into arbitrary packets. It's not possible to ensure that a piece of text is in the same packet. If you are typing in a terminal program, it's even likely that each character is sent in a separate packet. If you paste a long text into the terminal program, it's likely that you receive long packets of up to 64 characters.
- The received data is an array of characters. It's not a string (with a '\0' termination). So string functions such as `atoi` or `strlen` must not be used unless the data has been converted to a string.

In order to progress:

- Add code that detects when sufficient data has been received to process it. A typical approach is to use the linefeed character for it, i.e. you save all recieved data until a full line has been received. Then the entire line is processed.
- In the saved data, add a `'\0'` character. That way, the buffer becomes a string and can be processed with string functions.

It could look something like this:

```
char line_buffer[80];
int line_len = 0;

void CDC_ReceiveCallBack(uint8_t *buf, uint32_t len)
{
    // append received data to line buffer
    memcpy(line_buffer + line_len, buf, len);
    line_len += len;

    while (1) {
        // check for linefeed character
        char* line_feed = memchr(buf, '\n', line_len);
        if (line_feed == NULL)
            break;

        // add string termination
        *line_feed = '\0';
        process_line(line_buffer);

        // copy remaining data to start of line buffer
        line_len -= line_feed + 1 - line_buffer;
        memcpy(line_buffer, line_feed + 1, line_len);
    }
}

void process_line(char* line) {
    // do something with the line; string functions are ok
}
```

Note that the code is incomplete:

- It does not check if the received data fits into `line_buffer`.
- You will likely receive both a `'\r'` and `'\n'` character as a line separator. So you might want to remove the `'\r'` character.
- I haven't tested the code. It's likely missing some conversions from `void*` to `char*` or from `uint32_t` to `int`.

Comment: In practice, a ring buffer (circular buffer) is usually used, along with some sort of message terminators and a checksum.

Comment: @Groo Do you have some code? I've struggled in the past with ring buffers for messages with variable length? It get's ugly if the message no longer needs to be split.

Comment: We actually have a rather elaborate ring buffer implementation which abstracts pretty much all operations to allow it to be used similarly to a linear buffer. Perhaps overengineered for a small project, but it removes the need to copy data around the buffer and allows us to read the data from a different interrupt concurrently (one writer + one reader). For example, `rb_peek_u16_le(&rb, x)` will parse a little-endian uint16 value at offset `x` from the tail. But you're right, if one has to write it from scratch, there is quite a bit of work.

Comment: After struggling to find a good general purpose implementation for reading an arbitrary number of bytes - I decided to write one here: https://github.com/philrawlings/bluepill-usb-cdc-test
This essentially modifies `usb_cdc_if.c` to create a circular buffer and exposes additional functions (`CDC_GetRxBufferBytesAvailable_FS()`, `CDC_ReadRxBuffer_FS()` and `CDC_FlushRxBuffer_FS()`) which can be consumed from `main.c`. You could use this reading one byte at a time until you receive a line terminator.